# Is There a Search By Image Function in React-Native using Clarifai Api?

Tags: python, react-native, clarifai

I am trying to search by image using clarifai api, and I am using react native. The python code to search by image is app.inputs.search_by_image(filename=''), but how would I make a function to do that command in react native? I am trying to replicate the tutorial on this website in react native: https://www.clarifai.com/blog/search-images-by-visual-similarity-with-the-clarifai-api

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifai Support here.

There is a JS implementation of search_by_image and you can see how to use it at this link
https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/search/rank#by-image